# Need to make js work multiple times in a star rating system,bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

everyone.
I am using a simple star rating system,and I used it on the page 3 times. When i click one ,the other 2 take the same value. Need to make the js work for each one. Please be kind,I am a noob in js. 
Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<div class="star-rating" id="star-rating-2"> 
  <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="1"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="2"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="3"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="4"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="5"></span>
  <input type="hidden" name="rating-stars" class="rating-value" value="1">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var $star_rating = $('.star-rating .fa');

var SetRatingStar = function() {
  return $star_rating.each(function() {
    if (parseInt($star_rating.siblings('input.rating-value').val()) >= parseInt($(this).data('rating'))) {
      return $(this).removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
    } else {
      return $(this).removeClass('fa-star').addClass('fa-star-o');
    }
  });
};

$star_rating.on('click', function() {
  $star_rating.siblings('input.rating-value').val($(this).data('rating'));
  return SetRatingStar();
});

SetRatingStar();
```

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net or other code share site so we can see problem and modify code as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking on something like this, please check 
http://jsfiddle.net/unb3n8s1/3/, you need to find parent element and loop only on his children

```
var $star_rating = $('.star-rating .fa');

var SetRatingStar = function($star_rating_parent) {
  return $star_rating_parent.find('.fa').each(function() {
    if (parseInt($star_rating_parent.find('input.rating-value').val()) >= parseInt($(this).data('rating'))) {
      return $(this).removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
    } else {
      return $(this).removeClass('fa-star').addClass('fa-star-o');
    }
  });
};

$star_rating.on('click', function() {
  $(this).siblings('input.rating-value').val($(this).data('rating'));
  return SetRatingStar($(this).parent());
});
```

Comment: it works, just change value for <input type="hidden" so results are not visible on frontend, that's why just use developer tools to see results http://take.ms/eyWg7

Answer (score 0):

I changed just one line of the jquery and this seems to function correctly. The Click event stores the direct dom object you are trying to access, try this but with hidden instead of text inputs:

```js
var $star_rating = $('.star-rating .fa');

var SetRatingStar = function () {
    return $star_rating.each(function () {
        if (parseInt($star_rating.siblings('input.rating-value').val()) >= parseInt($(this).data('rating'))) {
            return $(this).removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
        } else {
            return $(this).removeClass('fa-star').addClass('fa-star-o');
        }
    });
};

$star_rating.on('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().find('input').val($(this).data('rating')); // <- edited line
    return SetRatingStar();
});

SetRatingStar();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="star-rating" id="star-rating-2"> <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="1">1</span>
 <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="2">2</span>
 <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="3">3</span>
 <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="4">4</span>
 <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="5">5</span>

    <input type="text" name="rating-stars" class="rating-value" value="1" />
</div>
<div class="star-rating" id="star-rating-2"> <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="1">1</span>
 <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="2">2</span>
 <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="3">3</span>
 <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="4">4</span>
 <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="5">5</span>

    <input type="text" name="rating-stars" class="rating-value" value="1" />
</div>
<div class="star-rating" id="star-rating-2"> <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="1">1</span>
 <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="2">2</span>
 <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="3">3</span>
 <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="4">4</span>
 <span class="fa fa-star-o" data-rating="5">5</span>

    <input type="text" name="rating-stars" class="rating-value" value="1" />
</div>
```

Comment: I rate the first product,and the same value goes to the 2 others. But someone answered me,and his code works. Thanks ,dude! :)

Comment: what browser are your using?